# Why does the axis of rotation of a thrown football rotate downwards as it travels along its trajectory?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque, projectile

When a quarterback throws a pass, the football is angled upwards relative to the surface of the field, but progressively rotates downwards along it's path of travel.  When initially released, I can't detect any rotation of the axis of rotation to explain this.  I'm thinking there must be some torque applied as a result of aerodynamic forces acting on the rotating football.  If this is true, what is the source of this torque?  Also, shouldn't the football precess as a result of a torque being applied to the axis of rotation?  Again, I can't see any evidence of precession of a spirally thrown football.

Comment: See On the Flight of the American Football. https://physics.fullerton.edu/~heidi/PROJECTS/football.pdf

Comment: I think there's a small amount of yaw, not obvious to the eye, but large enough that the air applies a torque about an axis in the vertical plane perpendicular to the flight path.  Due to precession, this torque causes the desired change in the axis of rotation.